# Changing Pandas Period to another frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling to handle some pandas period data. All I need is to easily change its frequency

Example DF

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'status' :  ['pending', 'pending','pending', 'canceled','canceled','canceled', 'confirmed', 'confirmed','confirmed'],
    'product' : ['afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard','afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard','afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard'],
    'brand' : ['brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_3','brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_3','brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_3'],
    'date' : [datetime(2022,1,1),datetime(2023,6,1),datetime(2020,1,12),datetime(2025,1,1),datetime(2024,1,1),datetime(2023,1,1),datetime(2021,1,1),datetime(2022,1,1),datetime(2022,1,1)],
    'gmv' : [100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100]})
```

[image: example dataframe output]

When I receive the dataframe, one of its columns is already converted "to_period('M')", so I cant just get the "to_period('y')"

Setting the month column on the example dataframe

```
data['month'] = data.date.dt.to_period('M')
```

The question is that I need to change the period frequency to a yearly period. So i tried the [pandas.series.asfreq](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.asfreq.html) execution

```
data['year'] = data.month.asfreq('Y')
```

and all I got is a NaT result.

[image: pandas series asfreq results]

But If I set my period column as index, the asfreq works as expected.

```
data['year'] = data['month']
data = data.set_index('year')
data = data.asfreq('Y')
```

[image: pandas periodindex asfreq]

What did I get wrong!?

Comment: In the example I could because the datetime column still there, but the real dataframe does not contain the datetime column anymore, only the period column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion arises from the fact that [`Series.asfreq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.asfreq.html) is used to convert the frequency of [`Series.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.index.html), not the frequency of [`Series.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html). The values of your initial index are of course simply integers:

```
data['month'].index
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=9, step=1)
```

Hence, `data['month'].asfreq('Y')` is trying to do this:

```
pd.date_range(start=0, end=9, freq='Y')
DatetimeIndex([], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='A-DEC')
```

which is of course quite nonsensical and explains the NaT values. We see now also why the following *does* work. With the step [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), you are creating a [`pd.PeriodIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.html) under the hood, so that you are now applying [`df.asfreq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) with a proper `pd.PeriodIndex`:

```
data['year'] = data['month']
data = data.set_index('year')
data = data.asfreq('Y')

data.index
PeriodIndex(['2022-01', '2023-06', '2020-01', '2025-01', '2024-01', '2023-01',
             '2021-01', '2022-01', '2022-01'],
            dtype='period[M]', name='year')
```

Finally, we see now that all of this is unnecessary. Simply apply `pd.PeriodIndex` to `data['month']` immediately and chain [`.asfreq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.asfreq.html):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'status' :  ['pending', 'pending','pending', 'canceled','canceled','canceled', 'confirmed', 'confirmed','confirmed'],
    'product' : ['afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard','afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard','afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard'],
    'brand' : ['brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_3','brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_3','brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_3'],
    'date' : [datetime(2022,1,1),datetime(2023,6,1),datetime(2020,1,12),datetime(2025,1,1),datetime(2024,1,1),datetime(2023,1,1),datetime(2021,1,1),datetime(2022,1,1),datetime(2022,1,1)],
    'gmv' : [100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100]})

data['month'] = data['date'].dt.to_period('M')
data['year'] = pd.PeriodIndex(data['month']).asfreq('Y')

data

      status    product    brand       date  gmv    month  year
0    pending  afiliates  brand_1 2022-01-01  100  2022-01  2022
1    pending   pre-paid  brand_2 2023-06-01  100  2023-06  2023
2    pending   giftcard  brand_3 2020-01-12  100  2020-01  2020
3   canceled  afiliates  brand_1 2025-01-01  100  2025-01  2025
4   canceled   pre-paid  brand_2 2024-01-01  100  2024-01  2024
5   canceled   giftcard  brand_3 2023-01-01  100  2023-01  2023
6  confirmed  afiliates  brand_1 2021-01-01  100  2021-01  2021
7  confirmed   pre-paid  brand_2 2022-01-01  100  2022-01  2022
8  confirmed   giftcard  brand_3 2022-01-01  100  2022-01  2022
```

Comment: Thanks man! I really does not understand why such method is able to work on periodindex but not on a period series.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply reset the index and re-order the resulting columns. So with your example DF:

```
data['month'] = data.date.dt.to_period('M')
data['year'] = data['month']
data = data.set_index('year').asfreq('Y').reset_index()
data= data.reindex(columns = ['status', 'product', 'brand', 'date','gmv', 'month', 'year'])
```

which gives:

```
      status    product    brand       date  gmv    month  year
0    pending  afiliates  brand_1 2022-01-01  100  2022-01  2022
1    pending   pre-paid  brand_2 2023-06-01  100  2023-06  2023
2    pending   giftcard  brand_3 2020-01-12  100  2020-01  2020
3   canceled  afiliates  brand_1 2025-01-01  100  2025-01  2025
4   canceled   pre-paid  brand_2 2024-01-01  100  2024-01  2024
5   canceled   giftcard  brand_3 2023-01-01  100  2023-01  2023
6  confirmed  afiliates  brand_1 2021-01-01  100  2021-01  2021
7  confirmed   pre-paid  brand_2 2022-01-01  100  2022-01  2022
8  confirmed   giftcard  brand_3 2022-01-01  100  2022-01  2022
```

Comment: But isn´t a smarter way than moving my column to index? I could tried to convert the period to datetime and get back to period, but all seems so inefficient